# Problems loading images with the <base> tag

Tags: html, radix

I've put the html `<base>` tag in the head so I can easier link to relative images and css files. So far so good and it works quite well, the only problem is that sometimes (I think once in every 5 times?) the images won't load properly.

The interesting thing is that it's only the images that are in an `<img>` tag that won't load sometimes, all the background images always work.

When I look at the source the url to the image seems correct and when I open the url in a new tab it also works.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's interesting...can you provide a demo? Maybe there's something you do or have that's different. I've used `<base>` and never had that problem before.

Answer (score 0):

When you use base for example /images and you have got image.png in this folder, then you should link it as image.png.